# Rxjava: Insert only works with single but not with completable

Tags: android, sqlite, rx-java, android-room, completable-future

So I have two DAO functions for inserting a new user:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
Completable addData(User user);

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
Single<Long> insert(User user);
```

The difference is that one function returns a `completable` and the other one a `Single<Long>` where `Long` equals the id of the new inserted user.

Corresponding `ViewModel` functions:

```
public Completable addData(User modelClass) {
    return Completable.fromAction(() -> appDatabase.userDao().addData(modelClass))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}

public Single<Long> addData2(User user) {
    return appDatabase.userDao().insert(user)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Last but not least the subscribe method in my android activity:

```
viewModel.addData(new User( ""+myEntireName.getText().toString(), "jlk"))
.subscribe(
() -> { 
 Toast.makeText(this, "Jähgermeister!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}, 
throwable -> {
Toast.makeText(this, "Error!" + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
});

viewModel.addData2(new User( ""+myEntireName.getText().toString(), "jlk"))
.subscribe(
newI -> { //onSucess
Toast.makeText(this, "Yeah i work: " + newI, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}, //onError
throwable -> {
Toast.makeText(this, "Error!" + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
});
```

So here is the issue: The Insert function which returns a `Completable` prints the Toast message but the user is not actually insertet. But if I use the function which returns a `Single<Long>` the User is inserted. Same goes for delete.

What can be the cause? Can Insert only work with `Single<Long>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the source of the issue:

```
return Completable.fromAction(() -> appDatabase.userDao().addData(modelClass))
```

`appDatabase.userDao().addData()` returns a `Completable`. Putting it inside of `fromAction()` means you will not subscribe to the `Completable` it returns, which means whatever work it's supposed to do will not actually happen. You need to use something like `Completable.defer(() -> ...)` instead, which will actually subscribe to the `Completable` returned by the call to `addData`.

Comment: thank you, that solved my problem. Is the defer function bad practise or can I use it with no issues when inserting?

Comment: `defer` just keeps the Dao's `addData` method from being called until the `Completable` is subscribed to. You typically only need this if whatever you're doing inside of `addData` isn't lazy. If `addData` is lazy, you can just omit the `defer` call altogether.